# How to make Out-GridView show rows?

Tags: powershell, gridview

I have a PowerShell table with 55 rows:

```
> $ds.tables[0].rows.count
55
```

When I display it in the command line, it displays fine:

```
> $ds.tables[0]
FIELD1                                    FIELD2
------                                    ------
r1v1                                      r1v2
etc                                       etc
```

However, when I try pipelining it to `Out-GridView` (`ogv`), I get a blank grid, with the two field headers, **but absolutley no rows**!

How do I display the rows from my table in a PowerShell `Out-GridView`?

**EDIT:** As requested, here is the code:

```
$provider = "Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties='Application=Windows';"
$sql = "SELECT top 100 System.itemname, system.itemurl FROM SYSTEMINDEX WHERE contains('frog')" 
$adapter = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter -Argument $sql, $provider
$ds = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$adapter.fill($ds)
$ds.tables[0]
$ds.tables[0] | ogv
```

**UPDATE:** As per the comment, I checked, and the machine is running PowerShell v2.0.

Comment: @PetSerAl Same results

Comment: Ah, I remember. It is `Out-GridView` v2 bug. It does not print values for properties with dot `.` in name. That should work: `$ds.tables[0] | select @{n='itemname';e='system.itemname'},@{n='itemurl';e='system.itemurl'} | ogv`.