# Dot in Powershell Out-GridView header hides columns

Tags: powershell, csv, out-gridview

How can I use dots in the header of an Out-GridView?

If a header in the Powershell Out-GridView contains a dot all columns of that header are empty.
Example:

```
echo "person.name,person-age`r`njohn,27" | ConvertFrom-Csv | Out-GridView
```

Environment: Windows 7, PSVersion 2 0 -1 -1

Tested it with Windows 8.1, PSVersion 4 0 -1 -1 there it works

Seems this is a bug at least in Version 2

Comment: Not able to reproduce with v5.0. Which version and host are you seeing this with?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085219/how-to-make-out-gridview-show-rows#comment57898562_35085219

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link from PetSerAl shows that my problem with dots in Out-GridView headers is a known bug in version 2 of the PowerShell.